# When xml is changed the swf file doesn't change

Tags: asp.net, xml, actionscript-3, flash, iis

I am trying to read values from `XML` to swf file ,so i have a xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GALLERY>


<IMAGE TITLE="ssasa">image1.jpg</IMAGE>
<IMAGE TITLE="oooo">image2.jpg</IMAGE>
<IMAGE TITLE="shop">image3.jpg</IMAGE>
</GALLERY>
```

In my AS3 `flash file` i have this code :

```
import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
import flash.system.Security;

var xml:XML;
var xmlList:XMLList;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost:15979/crossdomain.xml");
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost:15979/default.aspx"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
xml = XML(event.target.data);
xmlList = xml.children();
trace(xml.IMAGE[1].@TITLE);
txtname.text=xml.IMAGE[1].@TITLE;
}
```

In my timeline i have this :

[image]

As you can see i call my acionscript code in frame 22,but my problem is when i changed the data in xml file the swf file ,it doesn't apply to swf file and the swf file shows the old text on the screen ,but after closing the file it works fine and the new text appears.

I think it is because the iis  cachs the data .!!!

best regards

Comment: yes everything gets cached for efficiency. Just add at the end of your loading link: "?" + new Date().getTime().toString()

Comment: @BotMaster No it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally add this value to my request :

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:15979/default.aspx");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();  
variables.nocache = new Date().getTime(); 
// set up other URLVariables here
request.data = variables;
```